# Como referenciar outra coleção no Cloud Firestore do Firebase

Tags: banco-de-dados, angular, ionic, firebase

Estou começando a aprender Firebase, usando Cloud Firestore.
E me surge uma dúvida: Como eu posso relacionar coleções?
Eu vejo as coleções como tabelas, então eu teria uma coleção de Produtos, e uma de Categoria. E na coleção de Produtos, eu teria que ter o ID da de Categoria, para especificar que cada está em alguma categoria, mas como é um banco não relacional, e eu ainda estou aprendendo tudo isso, estou meio perdido. Qualquer ajuda serei muito agradecido.

[image: CloudFirestore]

Answer (score 0):

- Primeiro deve instanciar sua conexão firebase em um arquvi index.js dentro da pasta src/firebase, o arquivo deve conter

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    // verifique as configurações do seu projeto na sua conta firebase
    FIREBASE_CONFIGURATION
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);
```

---

- Dentro do arquivo que deseja acessar sua collection deve conter o seguinte código

```js
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

// dessa forma você irá acessar apenas o produto que
// contem esse id: 2dWbx6o4lSspIY7SJBCT
const docRef = doc(db, "Produto", "2dWbx6o4lSspIY7SJBCT");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  // Esse log contem os campos do seu documento
  
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

---

Caso ainda tenha duvidas consulte:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=pt-br
ou fique a vontade pra perguntar no chat

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Você tem duas abordagens:

No Produto você pode colocar o Id da Categoria, e com isso você tem a referência da categoria.
Outro ponto, o que eu mais uso, é salvar os dados da Categoria no Produto. 
Por exemplo:

```
categoria:{ id: OHUIGDAUYG23, nome: Gastronomia}
```

O segundo caso é melhor, pois assim que você recupera a informação do Produto já vem as informações da Categoria.

Você deve armazenar os seus dados levando em consideração o que vai exibir. Se não for exibir a Categoria no Produto, não precisa armazenar as informações da categoria, apenas o ID, caso contrário, é interessante armazenar as informações de Categoria no Produto, assim evita fazer uma nova consulta.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado por responder! Gostaria de entender melhor os 2 casos. No 1°, você diz que posso apenas colocar o ID da categoria na coleção de Produto, mas como faço isso? Eu tenho a Coleção Produto, nela tenho os documentos ID's gerados automaticamentes dos produtos que adicionei, e em cada documento tenho as informações..  Onde exatamente devo adicionar o ID da Categoria?  E esse  ID da categoria eu devo por um nome a ele ao invés de gerar automaticamente correto?  Obrigado pela ajuda novamente, pedir apenas um pouco de paciência pois sou novo com Firebase e também com programação.

Comment: Quando você cadastra um Produto você não diz de que categoria ele pertence? Você pode fazer o seguinte: Quando você for cadastrar um Produto, na página de cadastro teria um combobox com as Categorias recuperadas do Firebase. Preenche todas as informações sobre o Produto e seleciona uma Categoria. Com isso você pode salvar a informação completa de Categoria, {id:ouhdiuashd, nome: Gastronomia} no Produto: { nome: Salmão, valor: 50.00, categoria: {id:ouhdiuashd, nome: Gastronomia}}. Ou simplesmente apenas o id: { nome: Salmão, valor: 50.00, categoria: ouhdiuashd }.

Comment: Como disse antes, depende de como você vai usar a informação de Categoria. Quer exibir a categoria no Produto? Se sim a melhor opção é salvar todos os dados de Categoria no Produto: Ex:{ nome: Salmão, valor: 50.00, categoria: {id:ouhdiuashd, nome: Gastronomia}}. Caso contrário não há necessidade, apenas { nome: Salmão, valor: 50.00, categoria: ouhdiuashd } já é o suficiente. Tanto a 1ª opção, quanto a 2ª opção tem como você listar os produtos por categoria.